# Image loader animation showing every time appear on image in tableview

Tags: ios, chat, whatsapp, mbprogresshud

I am working on Chatting. So when I send the image to the user. I need to showing  animation like as same  Whatsapp upload Image. So I am using MBProgressHUD.it is working fine.But when I scrolling table view appear animation of all images.  I wrote this code in this section cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.imageview animated:YES];

    // Set the annular determinate mode to show task progress.
    hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeAnnularDeterminate;
    hud.label.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Loading...", @"HUD loading title");

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED, 0), ^{
        // Do something useful in the background and update the HUD periodically.
        [self doSomeWorkWithProgress];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [hud hideAnimated:YES];
        });
    });

    doSomeWorkWithProgress {
    self.canceled = NO;
    // This just increases the progress indicator in a loop.
    float progress = 0.0f;
    while (progress < 1.0f) {
        if (self.canceled) break;
        progress += 0.01f;
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // Instead we could have also passed a reference to the HUD
            // to the HUD to myProgressTask as a method parameter.
            [MBProgressHUD HUDForView:self.navigationController.view].progress = progress;
        });
        usleep(50000);
    }
}
```

it's works fine.but when I scrolling my tableview again loading animation in all image cell. how to resolve it ?? please help me.

Comment: You're always telling it to show "Loading" then `doSomeWorkWithProgress`... somehow you must know here if you need to `doSomeWorkWithProgress` here or not... Try to store progress information in a NSArray or something and check it before `dispatch_async`

Comment: @farzadshbfn, Thank you, Once see my updated question.

Comment: Define an integer in your class (let's say **downloadComplete**). inside `doSomeWorkWithProgress`, before _dispatch_async_ write `self.downloadComplete = 1`, inside _dispatch_async_ write: `self.downloadComplete = 2` and inside your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` right before _dispatch_async_ write: `if (self.downloadComplete == 0)`... by my understanding of your **viewContorller** and the mechanism you used, it should work ;)

Comment: @farzadshbfn.Thank you for patience. I'm tried from my end. But Now, not disappear on all image and even also i am uploading image. could you please implement of that. Actually i am new Developer.

Answer (score 0):

Write this outside of your `@interface ViewController`

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, DownloadState) {
    DownloadStateStopped,
    DownloadStateStarted,
    DownloadStateCompleted,
};
```

And hold an instance to it in your `ViewController`

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) DownloadState downloadState;
```

Set it's initial value:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    // your code
    self.downloadState = DownloadStateStopped;
}
```

And now fix `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.imageview animated:YES];

    // Set the annular determinate mode to show task progress.
    hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeAnnularDeterminate;
    hud.label.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Loading...", @"HUD loading title");

    if (self.downloadState == DownloadStateStopped) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED, 0), ^{
            // Do something useful in the background and update the HUD periodically.
            [self doSomeWorkWithProgress];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [hud hideAnimated:YES];
            });
        });  
    }
}
```

And in your `doSomeWorkWithProgress`

```
doSomeWorkWithProgress {
    self.canceled = NO;
    // This just increases the progress indicator in a loop.
    float progress = 0.0f;

    self.downloadState = DownloadStateStarted;

    while (progress < 1.0f) {
        if (self.canceled) break;
        progress += 0.01f;
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // Instead we could have also passed a reference to the HUD
            // to the HUD to myProgressTask as a method parameter.
            [MBProgressHUD HUDForView:self.navigationController.view].progress = progress;
        });
        usleep(50000);
    }

    self.downloadState = DownloadStateCompleted;
}
```

p.s: Don't just copy/paste the code to check if it's working, grasp the idea ;)

Comment: @farzadshfn  same issues again. its appearing on all images.

Comment: Do you have a progressLoader on each cell? Because the code you've provides tells otherwise! I assumed you only have on loader at top or something...

Comment: @farzadhfn yes, i having progressLoader on each image cell. but here its showing when i uploading new image and scroll up & down. i did not find out this problem , where did i mistake in ???

Comment: @farzadshfn Is there any example ?? if yes please tell me. like uploading image from phone to server. please help me.

Comment: Don't care about the network thing, download the project and check how did they manage the ui... [HalfTunes](https://www.raywenderlich.com/110458/nsurlsession-tutorial-getting-started) ;)

Comment: @farzadshfn, Thank you. I am writing in objective C.